# How to create name tags using !Join and !FindInMap in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a tag using join and findinmap in the AWS cloud formation template, it but doesn't seems to work.

```
Mappings:
    AccountToStage:
        "123456789012":
            StageName: Beta
    Beta:
      us-east-1:
        KeyName: "Batman"
```

```
     Tags:
      -
        Key: "Name"
        Value: !Join
                  - '-'
                  - - !FindInMap
                      - !FindInMap
                          - AccountToStage
                          - !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
                          - StageName
                      - !Ref "AWS::Region"
                      - KeyName
                    - 'DBVolume'
```

expected output: "Batman-DBVolume"

Any pointers are much appreciated ?

Answer (score 0):

Test tags on an ssm parm. Key is to use combination of Json and Yaml.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Test"
Mappings:
  AccountToStage:
    "123456789012":
      StageName: Beta
  Beta:
    us-east-1:
      KeyName: "Batman"
Resources:
  SmsLambdaParameter:
    Type: "AWS::SSM::Parameter"
    Properties:
      Name: "/Dev/Lambda-Param"
      Type: "String"
      Value: "Test"
      Tags:
        {
          "Name":
            {
              "Fn::Join":
                [
                  "-",
                  [
                    !FindInMap [
                      !FindInMap [
                        AccountToStage,
                        !Ref AWS::AccountId,
                        "StageName",
                      ],
                      !Ref AWS::Region,
                      "KeyName",
                    ],
                    "DBVolume",
                  ],
                ],
            },
        }
```

[image]